# "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" on inserting of element to reserved position of List

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have the `List` of `Count` equals `2` but currently both positions are empty:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(paginationCollection.PagesContent.Count); // 0
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(paginationCollection.PagesContent.Capacity); // 2
```

Here is, the `paginationCollection` is the instance of

```cs
public class PaginationCollection<Item>
{

  public readonly uint PagesCount;

  public List<List<Item>> PagesContent;

  public PaginationCollection(
    uint pagesCount,
    byte numerationFrom
  )
  {
    
    PagesCount = pagesCount;
    PagesContent = new List<List<Item>>(numerationFrom == 0 ? (int)pagesCount : (int)pagesCount + 1);
  }
}
```

When I try to add some items to position number 1, I get the`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```cs
for (int pageNumber = pagesNumerationFrom; pageNumber < lastPageNumber; pageNumber++)
{

  paginationCollection.PagesContent.Insert(
    pageNumber, // 1 for current data
    // ↓ Confirmed that GetRange operation does not cause the Exception
    flatCollection.GetRange((int)elementStartingPositionForCurrentPage, (int)elementEndingPositionForCurrentPage) 
  );

   // ...
}
```

From the viewpoint of logic, the position number `1` is currently empty, but the inserting operation number be available (AFAIK in C# case, the `Capacity` must be greater or equal to target position).

Comment: `List.Insert(int index, T item)`, where `index` it's The zero-based index at which item should be inserted. You are trying to use a non-existing position, you need to subtract 1 from `pageNumber`

Comment: @Juan, Thank you for the comment. Really I was going to keep the 0th position empty (when `numerationFrom` is `1`). Is it possible ? If no, I'll insert the empty child list to 0th position.

Comment: You need to start at `0`, if you want to have your page start at `1` then you already have the anwer

Comment: That is a bad class. You should use `public class PaginationCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Item>`. Then your class IS the collection, instead of containing the collection. All the standard collection functionality will be inherited without your providing any additional code.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand the constructor `List<T>(int capacity)`. It will create an empty List<T> rather than that filled with the set number of default(T).

Comment: You definitely have misunderstood what `capacity` means in this context. A `List<T>` contains an internal array in which the data is actually stored. The `Capacity` is the size of that array but the `Count` is the actual number of items the list contains. Any index equal to or greater than `Count` is invalid, regardless of `Capacity`. The point of `Capacity` is that, once you add items beyond that, the list must create a new, larger array and copy elements to it from the old one, which hurts performance. If you know you need at least N items then set that `Capacity` at the start.

Comment: If you need a sparse _array_ where you need to put elements at arbitrary positions, you should use a `Dictionary<int, Item>`.

Answer (score 1):

A `List`, among other things, offers the flexibility to create a collection of items without specifying the size at the start, it works like magic as it just adjusts the size when you keep adding items to it. Behind the scenes, a list is actually nothing else but an `Array`.

When we create a list with `new List();` This is what happens behind the scenes.

A new array with the size `4` is created.

The list has two properties namely `Count` and `Capacity` among others.

**Count:** The number of items in the list, which will be `0` initially, since there will be no elements added into it

**Capacity:** The number of items that can be added to the list, which will be set to the size of the initial array, in this case, `4`.

As you keep adding items to the list, once the `Count` has reached the `Capacity`, the list will:

1. Create a new array with twice the current capacity `Capacity * 2` which means an array of size `8`
2. Copy all the previous items to this new array
3. Destroy the old array

At the end of this cycle, `Count` remains `4` while `Capacity` becomes `8`.

This whole process is repeated as long as you keep adding items to the list. The downside to this is that it takes away some performance doing all these extra things.

If we have a rough idea in advance about the number of items that the list will probably going to contain, e.g. `100`, what you could then do is initialize  the list like `new List(100);` which means the initial `Capacity` is going to be `100`, thus as long as `Count` is less than a 100, all these steps won't be performed, so we get a performance improvement over it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=net-7.0#definition

According to the documentation, if you added an item to a position that is less than `0` or greater than `Count`, you'll get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, which in your case is correct because although there is space available in the list, there are no items in there, so it complains.